# MySQL SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have database session enable, when website got thousands of visitor. It gives me error

```
[30-Apr-2014 04:27:12 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded;
 try restarting transaction' in public_html/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php:458
Stack trace:
#0 public_html/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php(458): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 public_html/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php(424): DboSource->_execute('UPDATE `yuldi_d...', Array)
#2 public_html/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Mysql.php(400): DboSource->execute('UPDATE `yuldi_d...')
#3 public_html/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(1821): Mysql->update(Object(cake_sessions), Array, Array)
#4 public_html/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Session/DatabaseSession.php(117): Model->save(Array)
#5 [internal function]: DatabaseSession->write('66336365f5fc91c...', 'Config|a:3:{s:9...')
#6 [internal function]: session_write_close()
#7 {main}
  thrown in public_html/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php on line 458
```

I want to know, how can i check MySQL insert queries per second, is there any commands to check that using ssh ?
is there changes in my.cnf required ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wan't to check the queries/s in live you can use the mysqladmin tool with some options:

```
[root@db-prod-01 ~]# mysqladmin extended-status -uroot -p -i 1 -r | grep 'Com_insert '
Enter password: 
| Com_insert                            | 59863746      |
| Com_insert                            | 1             |
| Com_insert                            | 2             |
| Com_insert                            | 9             |
| Com_insert                            | 2             |
| Com_insert                            | 2             |
| Com_insert                            | 3             |
| Com_insert                            | 2             |
| Com_insert                            | 3             |
| Com_insert                            | 6             |
```

- **extended-status:** return the result of `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;`
- **-i 1 -r:**  Execute the `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` every second (one line by second)
- **| grep 'Com_insert':** Shows only `INSERTS` statements

Note that `Com_insert` is a cumulativ counter the first line shows the nominal counter value and at each iteration of mysqladmin, a substraction is made to show you how there were insertions during the time you setted (here `-i 1` is each 1 second).

By the way, if you want some infos for your error (1205) it's the **InnoDB Engine** that should check because it's the only way to see which of your query (or queries) is/are stucking your DB.

You can find infos on current and past transactions that lock your DB with:

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; -- In a MySQL prompt
```

Max.

Comment: how can i check that my system current resources capable to how much workload of insert query. will also help if there any great tool to test high workload on server

Answer (score -1):

`Laravel Database Session` also caused similar issue. I think you can refer to it based on situation below:-

The `Garbage Collection` function of the `Laravel Database Session` to cause `sessions` table locked when performing `deletion` of the `expired session`.

There are **two ways** to reduce this issue:

**First**, Ignore `Garbage Collection` function by manually amend the `DatabaseSessionHandler.php` located at `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session` to comment `gc` function, but it will be caused the session will never expired until perform logout.

For example:

```
  public function gc($lifetime)
    {
        //$this->getQuery()->where('last_activity', '<=', Carbon::now()->getTimestamp() - $lifetime)->delete();
    }
```

**Second**, add Index of the column `last_activity` to table 'sessions' for reduce the range of lock from `entire table` into `row-level`. Be careful while performing this action, it will cause down time while perform add index depends of the row size of you
`sessions` table

**Note: Take your own risk while perform both actions, better test of localhost environment then update to the production side.**